# my custom pipe don't work with SPIN DUPLICATES and ARRAY

Tags: modeling

my custom pipe don't work with array , spin duplicates and array tool. [image]

any idea what is wrong and how to fix it? this tube is made from circles, then this circles in 7 segments and twisted 1 time and a spiral. with a tube from ADD all work[image] beautiful.

Comment: one question, how many verts does your scene have? If you Blender starts to not respond, it may be because it is too heavy for your hardware

Comment: yes, i thinked to this ,too. after a while is doing the operation. this is just for this one app. vertices i think was under 100000 in this issue.

Comment: But you still have those modifiers unapplied or applied?

Comment: to this is not need to apply like the blender ones. they just do it and remain like that. in my opinion is something inside my tube, but i don't have the knowledge to look after it. a friend from here helped me in blender in 2.79-2.8 and later. maybe is from this oldest versions in the tube history ? i say this because with a simple tube was all fine.

Comment: with ARRAY from blender the counts are put it on the z axe where the pivot point is and nothing more, this before and after applying.

Comment: maybe this blender version has a problem? with the cylinder and array tool is doing nothing. and when i paste an object +cylinder+array is doing weird thinks, positioning the few cylinders in z axe up+down and in x axes left+right. the pivot point is at 3d cursor.

Comment: blender in spin duplicates is putting the duplicates in spiral stairs , from 0 to +180-right side  and -180-left side =360 degree, and from the side is like in the second image